# Activity Assigner - that randomly assigns each student to an activity

Tags: java, object-oriented

I am trying to improve my object-oriented modelling and programming skills and hence made an attempt at solving the problem statement from [this link](http://coweb.cc.gatech.edu/cs1316/uploads/629/Spring_2008_Breaking_the_Problem_Down_Problem_Solving_in_OO_Computer_Science.1.pdf).

#### Problem Statement

> A teacher wants you to help her write a program that will randomly
> assign each of her students to an activity at the various activity
> tables available in her classroom. Each activity table knows its
> activity, the materials needed for the activity, the students at the
> table and how many chairs are left. The activity tables available are
> the math table, the art table, the reading table and the computer
> table and their respective activities are doing math, drawing, reading
> and playing on the computer.

I tried my best in coming up with the above objects. Can this be scenario be modelled in a better way?

**ActivityTableAssignerMain.java:**

```
public class ActivityTableAssignerMain {
    private static final int TOTAL_STUDENTS = 50;
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> studentsInClass = getStudentsList();
        
        TablesController tablesController = new TablesController();
        tablesController.addActivityTable(new MathActivityTable(10));
        tablesController.addActivityTable(new DrawingActivityTable(15));
        tablesController.addActivityTable(new ReadingActivityTable(16));
        tablesController.addActivityTable(new ComputerPlayActivityTable(8));
        
        ActivityTableAssigner assigner = new ActivityTableAssigner(tablesController);
        assigner.assign(studentsInClass);
    }
    
    public static List<String> getStudentsList(){
        List<String> students = new ArrayList<>();
        
        for(int i=1; i <= TOTAL_STUDENTS; i++){
            students.add("Student " + i);
        }
        return students;
    }
}
```

**ActivityTableAssigner.java:**

```
/**
 * The primary logic class that loads the total students in the class and 
 * assigns them to a Random activity table. 
 *
 */
public class ActivityTableAssigner {
    private TablesController tableController;
    private RandomTableGetter randomTableGetter;
    
    public ActivityTableAssigner(TablesController controller) {
        this.tableController = controller;
    }
    
    public void assign(List<String> studentsInClass){
        if (tableController.totalTables() == 0){
            System.out.println("No Activity Tables found....");
            return;
        }
        performAssignment(studentsInClass);
    }
    
    private void performAssignment(List<String> studentsInClass){
        randomTableGetter = new RandomTableGetter(tableController);
        
        for (String student : studentsInClass){
            ActivityTable randomTable = randomTableGetter.get();
            randomTable.addStudent(student);
            
            System.out.println("'"+student+"' assigned to "+randomTable.toString() + " table.");
            
            if (tableController.allTablesOccupied()){
                System.out.println("All the tables have been occupied");
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**RandomTableGetter.java:**

```
public class RandomTableGetter {
    
    private TablesController tablesController;
    private Random random = new Random();
    
    public RandomTableGetter(TablesController tablesController){
        this.tablesController = tablesController;
    }

    /**
     * Randomly retrieves an Activity table only if it not empty
     * @return - random ActivityTable
     */
    public ActivityTable get(){
        return getRandomTable();
    }
    
    private ActivityTable getRandomTable() {
        while (tablesController.hasTables()){
            ActivityTable randomActivityTable = tablesController.getTable(generateRandomNumber());
            
            if (randomActivityTable.isFullyOccupied()) {
                tablesController.relieveTable(randomActivityTable);
                continue;
            }
            return randomActivityTable;
        }
        return null;
    }
    
    
    /**
     * Generates Random number between 0 -> (TotalTables - 1)
     * @return
     */
    private int generateRandomNumber(){
        if (tablesController.totalTables() <= 1 )
            return 0;
        
        int bound = tablesController.totalTables() - 1;
        return random.nextInt(bound);
    }
}
```

**TablesController.java:**

```
/**
 * A wrapper class for managing the addition/retrieval of the various activity tables
 *
 */
public class TablesController {
    private List<ActivityTable> activityTables;
    
    public TablesController() {
        activityTables = new ArrayList<>();
    }
    
    public TablesController(Collection<ActivityTable> actTables) {
        activityTables = new ArrayList<>(actTables);
    }
    
    public void addActivityTable(ActivityTable table){
        activityTables.add(table);
    }
    
    public ActivityTable getTable(int index){
        return activityTables.get(index);
    }
    
    public int totalTables(){
        return activityTables.size();
    }
    
    public boolean hasTables(){
        return activityTables.size() > 0;
    }

    /**
     * Relieving (removing) a table if it has been fully occupied.
     * @param table
     */
    public void relieveTable(ActivityTable table){
        activityTables.remove(table);
    }
    
    public boolean allTablesOccupied(){
        for (ActivityTable activityTable : activityTables){
            if (!activityTable.isFullyOccupied()){
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

**Activity.java:**

```
public interface Activity {
    public void perform();
    public List<String> getRequiredItems();
}
```

**Activity Implementaion classes:**

```
/* ComputerActivity.java */
public class ComputerActivity implements Activity {
    @Override
    public void perform() {
        System.out.println("Computer activity started");
    }
    @Override
    public List<String> getRequiredItems() {
        return Arrays.asList(new String[]{"Computer", "Username-Password"});
    }
}

/* DrawingActivity.java */
public class DrawingActivity implements Activity {
    @Override
    public void perform() {
        System.out.println("Drawing activity started");
    }
    @Override
    public List<String> getRequiredItems() {
        return Arrays.asList(new String[]{"Pencil", "Drawing Page", "Colors"});
    }
}

/* MathActivity.java */
public class MathActivity implements Activity  {
    @Override
    public void perform() {
        System.out.println("Math activity started");
    }
    @Override
    public List<String> getRequiredItems() {
        return Arrays.asList(new String[]{"Notebook", "Calculator", "Pencil"});
    }
}

/* ReadingActivity.java */
public class ReadingActivity implements Activity {
    @Override
    public void perform() {
        System.out.println("Reading activity started");
    }
    @Override
    public List<String> getRequiredItems() {
        return Arrays.asList(new String[]{"Book"});
    }
}
```

**ActivityTable.java (Abstract class):**

```
public abstract class ActivityTable {
    protected List<String> studentsAtTable;
    protected int totalChairs;
    protected Activity activity;
    
    public ActivityTable(int chairs) {
        this.totalChairs = chairs;
    }
    
    public Activity getActivity() {
        return activity;
    }
    
    public int chairsRemaining() {
        return totalChairs - studentsAtTable.size();
    }
    
    public boolean isFullyOccupied(){
        return chairsRemaining() == 0;
    }
    
    public void addStudent(String name) {
        if (chairsRemaining() <= 0){
            System.out.println("Table is full");
            return;
        }
        studentsAtTable.add(name);
    }
}
```

**ActivityTable Implementaion classes:**

```
/* ReadingActivityTable.java */
public class ReadingActivityTable extends ActivityTable  {
    public ReadingActivityTable(int chairs) {
        super(chairs);
        activity = new ReadingActivity();
        studentsAtTable = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ReadingActivityTable";
    }
}

/* MathActivityTable.java */
public class MathActivityTable extends ActivityTable {
    public MathActivityTable(int chairs) {
        super(chairs);
        activity = new MathActivity();
        studentsAtTable = new ArrayList<>();
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "MathActivityTable";
    }
}

/* DrawingActivityTable.java */
public class DrawingActivityTable extends ActivityTable  {
    public DrawingActivityTable(int chairs) {
        super(chairs);
        activity = new DrawingActivity();
        studentsAtTable = new ArrayList<>();
    }
    
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "DrawingActivityTable";
    }
}

/* ComputerPlayActivityTable.java */
public class ComputerPlayActivityTable extends ActivityTable  {
    public ComputerPlayActivityTable(int chairs) {
        super(chairs);
        activity = new ReadingActivity();
        studentsAtTable = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ComputerPlayActivityTable";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, it looks good (model wise). I have a few remarks:

### Number of students?

You have 50 students, but 49 places for tables. Is this intentional?

### Student

I would create a `Student` class. Experience taught me that every time I used a simple `String` to represent a domain object, I ended up by changing it to a full class later on. Just start out with the basics (`String name`, `hashCode()` and `equals()`)

```
public class Student
{
   private final String name;

   public Student (String name)
   {
       if (name == null) throw new IllegalArgumentException("'name' cannot be 'null'");

       this.name = name;
   }

   public int hashCode()
   {
      return name.hashCode();
   }

   ..
}
```

### Error / Exception flow

There is no way to tell if the assignment went wrong, except from the message that goes to the standard out. You could return an result, for example a simple boolean indicating if the assignment was succesful. Alternatively, you could throw a custom `Exception` when it is impossible to assign the students.

It is not the task of the Assigner to do error logging/printing.

### Overengineering?

I think your `TableController` and `RandomTableGetter` are a bit overengineerd. What is their added value? You can implement a `Collection` (`List`, or `Set`) of `ActivityTable` and have a `getRandomAvailableTable()` method in the `ActivityTableAssigner`. Alternate behaviour can be coded in a different `ActivityTableAssigner`.

The `RandomTableGetter` is also doing full-table-checks, so a better name might be `RandomAvialableTableGetter`.

### Assignment algorithm

I would solve the assignment with generating a permutation instead of randomly trying to assign students to tables.

You could for example do this:

```
Collections.shuffle(students)
```

The collection of students will be shuffled and you can assign them simply by iterating the collection, *because to order is already random*.

### Better OO modelling of ActivityTable

Consider your constructor:

```
 public ActivityTable(int chairs) {
        this.totalChairs = chairs;
    }
```

This creates an 'invalid' class, as it has no Activity. Also you should require that there is always a list of students. Then, you could pass the name of the table as well, and reuse it in the `toString()`, so better implement it like this:

```
 public ActivityTable(String name, Activity activity, int chairs) {
        this.name = name;
        this.totalChairs = chairs;
        this.activity = activity;
        this.studentsAtTable = new ArrayList<>()
    }
```

And in the abstract ActivityTable:

```
public String toString()
{
     return this.name;
}
```

Saved a lot of repetition in the implementing subclasses as well.

```
public class ReadingActivityTable extends ActivityTable  {
    public ReadingActivityTable(int chairs) {
        super("ReadingActivityTable", new ReadingActivity(), chairs);
    }
}

public class MathActivityTable extends ActivityTable {
    public MathActivityTable(int chairs) {
        super("MathActivityTable", new MathActivity(), chairs);
    }
}
```

### Easier to read for loop

This `for` loop (with a start from 1 and a `<=`)

```
 for(int i=1; i <= TOTAL_STUDENTS; i++){
            students.add("Student " + i);
 }
```

Can be changed to the 'normal' form:

```
 for(int i=0; i < TOTAL_STUDENTS; i++){
            students.add("Student " + (i+1));
 }
```

Rationale is that this is the easiest for loop to read as there are no exceptions from the standard.

Comment: First of all, thanks for the great insights, really appreciate it.  I will try reply to your questions one by one.

Comment: _You have 50 students, but 49 places for tables. Is this intentional?_ : Thats just me testing with differing input values.

Comment: _I would solve the assignment with generating a permutation instead of randomly trying to assign students to tables._: Intriguing...can you elaborate on that or point me to a link ?

Comment: _Also this for look (with a start from 1 and a <=)_ : any specific reason for this? as I believe both achieve the same output.

Comment: I added some extra information to answer your questions.

Answer (score 2):

Good feedback form @RobAu.

I would add a few point on OOP: I do not understand the added value of subclassing the Activity. Fundamentally, all Activity subclasses **do** a similar thing, the difference is akin to a configuration/parameter change, like using its actual `activityName` in `toString`.

This kind of observation makes me think this class network would be better implemented as various instances of a single class, rather than (effectively) [singletons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) of many sub-classes. To help parameterize and finalize (I like [immutable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object) objects) the `ActivityImpl` class, you might use an `ActivityBuilder` - I'll make it [fluent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface#Java), it's trendy ;)

ActivityImpl.java:

```
protected class ActivityImpl implements Activity{
    private final String activityName;
    private final List<String> required = new ArrayList<>();
    public ActivityImpl(String activityName, List<String> requiredItems){
         this.activityName = activityName;
         this.requiredItems.addAll(requiredItems); // defensive copy
    }
    @Override
    public void perform() {
        System.out.println(activityName + " started");
    }
    @Override
    public List<String> getRequiredItems() {
        return requiredItems;
    }
}
```

ActivityBuilder class:

```
public class ActivityBuilder {
    private String activityName;
    private List<String> required = new ArrayList<>();
    public ActivityBuilder(String activityName){
        this.activityName = activityName;
    }
    public ActivityBuilder withName(String activityName) {
        this.activityName = activityName;
        return this;
    }
    public ActivityBuilder require(String... items){
        for(String item:items){
            this.required.add(item);
        }
        return this;
    }
    public static ActivityBuilder withName(String activityName){
        return new ActivityBuilder(activityName);
    }
    public Activity build(){
        return new ActivityImpl(activityName, required);
    }
}
```

Example Usage:

```
Activity readingActivity = ActivityBuilder.withName("Drawing").require("Pencil", "Drawing Page", "Colors").build();
```

---

Secondly, as @RobAu noted, the `ActivityTable` structure also needs cleaning up. There is currently a very strong [coupling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_(computer_programming)#Disadvantages) between `Activity` sub-classes, and `ActivityTable` sub-classes. Yet the `DrawingActivityTable` for example does not make use of the knowledge of its `DrawingActivity`'s *exact* type. That is to be expected after all, because as we've seen, the `Activity` sub-classes do not bring any special functionality with them (all methods are inherited from the interface, all implementations are similar)!

Therefore, the coupling is completely unnecessary.
(Additionally, nothing forces the sub-classes to initialise the `ActivityTable.activity` field, which I find worrying.)

First of all, all `ActivityTable` sub-types could be destroyed, leaving only a concrete `ActivityTable` who wouldn't know which of the Activity sub-type it handles. This is my preferred solution, because I don't see why a *table* should know precisely what is going on on it?

If you wanted to keep Strong typing on the Activities, an elegant solution would be to make `ActivityTable` a (concrete) *generic* class like so:

```
public class ActivityTable<T extends Activity> {
    protected final List<String> studentsAtTable;
    protected final int totalChairs;
    protected final T activity;

    public ActivityTable(T activity, int chairs) {
        this.totalChairs = chairs;
        this.activity = activity;
        this.studentsAtTable = new ArrayList<>(chairs);
    }

    public T getActivity() {
        return activity;
    }

    public int chairsRemaining() {
        return totalChairs - studentsAtTable.size();
    }

    public boolean isFullyOccupied(){
        return chairsRemaining() == 0;
    }

    public void addStudent(String name) {
        if (chairsRemaining() <= 0){
            System.out.println("Table is full");
            return;
        }
        studentsAtTable.add(name);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return activity.getName() + "ActivityTable"; // Assuming you add getName() to interface 'Activity' !
    }
}
```

As you can see, I made the fields final (not necessary, feel free to undo **if** your table ever changes of Activity, for example) and I initialized them as early as possible (straight in the constructor) so there can't ever be in an ill-defined state. Remember, if [it *can* go wrong, it absolutely will](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Murphy's_law).

The only improvement this brings however, is that if you have a drawing table, you'll be able to obtain a drawing Activity if you find that useful:

```
ActivityTable<DrawingActivityTable> drawingTable = new ActivityTable<>(new DrawingActivity());
DrawingActivity drawingActivity = drawingTable.getActivity();
```

---

Small advice: when you find yourself initializing a field in the same way in all sub-classes (I'm thinking the `studentsAtTable` and `activity` field in each ActivityTable sub-classes), it might be a good idea to either:

- Bring the initialization into the super constructor
- Put the initilization at the declaration

If it bothers you because you want sub-classes to be able to change implementation (useless here, but who knows), do this early initialization still, but do initilize using a protected, concrete, overridable provider method:

```
public class ActivityTable {
    protected final List<String> studentsAtTable;
    protected final int totalChairs;
    protected final Activity activity;

    public ActivityTable(Activity activity, int chairs) {
        this.totalChairs = chairs;
        this.activity = activity;
        this.studentsAtTable = initStudentsAtTable();
    }
    protected List<String> initStudentsAtTable(){ // The provider method
        return new ArrayList<>();
    }
    [...]
}
```

And the special sub-class:

```
public class ActivityWithSpecialStudentsList extends ActivityTable {
    public ActivityWithSpecialStudentsList(Activity activity, int chairs) {
        super(activity, chairs);
    }
    @Override
    protected List<String> initStudentsAtTable(){ // Special provider method!
        return new SpecialLinkedList<>();
    }
}
```

---

Final word: I fully concur with @RobAu on making a `Student` Object. I would simply extends this good advice to an `Item` Object for the items required for the activities.

Comment: Great addition Sylvain!